# JQuery code issues while calling functions on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am new to node.js and Jquery.

In the following code on the button click i have run a task and we cannot predict when will that task will complete 
while completing the task i will get a test result and stored in  DB.

Here is my html code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:10px;">
      <div id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px; display: none; ">
        <img src="./images/spinner.gif" />Running the test...
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="runBtn">RUN</button>
```

in button click first i write the code to run the task and we cannot predict when will it complete.After storing data in DB i have to fetch that data,it is also i have to call on the button click function.

```
$('#runBtn').click(function() {
var unitData 
.....
.....
// For running the task
   $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/runTask",
      dataType: "json",
      data: unitData,
      success: function (value) {
        console.log("Data saved succesfully");
      },
    });

// For fetching the result of task      

    $('#testResult').html('<img src="./images/spinner.gif" /> Running the test...');
        $('#testResult').show();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/getReport',
          cache: false
        }).done(function (html) { 
          $("#testResult").html( htm );
          $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
        }).fail(function () {
          $("#testResult").html("Failed to run the test");
          $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
        });      

    })
```

What i need is on button click i have to display a spinner image with test is running...(we cannot predict when will test complte)and after test complete storing data in db(it is working fine) and have to show that data in webpage and disappear spinner image.

Now what happend is while i clicking the run button the test will run and at the same time calling the `'/gerReport'` and returing null value.I need to call `/getReport` only after the test result come and show the spinner image with text test is running..

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var $testResultElement = $("#testResult"),
    onRunTaskCompleted = function () {
        console.log("Data saved succesfully");

        // Task running is complete, so now we can get the report
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getReport',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (html) { 
            $testResultElement.html(html);
        }).fail(function () {
            $testResultElement.html("Failed to run the test");
        }).always(function () {
            $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    };

$('#runBtn').click(function() {
    // var unitData
    // .....
    // .....
    $testResultElement.html('<img src="./images/spinner.gif" /> Running the test...').show();

    // For running the task
   $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/runTask",
        dataType: "json",
        data: unitData,
        success: onRunTaskCompleted
    });
```

Here's the logic:

- When button is clicked, first display the spinner (running the
  test...)
- Start the task. Notice how I changed the success property of the ajax
  call. I made a separate function to handle 'success' to make your
  code a bit easier to follow (for yourself)
- onRunTaskCompleted is run when the task is done. It will do the call
  'getReport'. The spinner is still spinning!
- When the call 'getReport' returns, we set the html that is returned,
  or the message 'Failed to run the test'. I added an always-callback
  to remove the disabled attribute from the edit button. This is
  because you wanted to do it both on done and on fail, and always is
  the ideal way, since it gets run both on done and fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code when save data record successfully something like that

```
$('#runBtn').click(function() {
var unitData 
.....
.....
// For running the task
   $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/runTask",
      dataType: "json",
      data: unitData,
      success: function (value) {
        console.log("Data saved succesfully");

// For fetching the result of task  
        $('#testResult').html('<img src="./images/spinner.gif" /> Running the test...');
        $('#testResult').show();
       $.ajax({
         url: '/getReport',
        cache: false
       }).done(function (html) { 
         $("#testResult").html( htm );
         $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
       }).fail(function () {
         $("#testResult").html("Failed to run the test");
         $('#edit').removeAttr("disabled");
       }); 


      },
    });
})
```